# regexp. Как не пропускать символ новой строки '\n' в регулярных выражениях ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.6

Через это регулярное выражение (проверка ip адреса):

```
import re
def ipv4_address(ip):
        return (bool(re.match(
        '^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}
        ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$', ip))
        if True else False)
```

Проходит этот ip и выдает True(но должен выдавать False):

```
print(ipv4_address("127.0.0.1\n"))
```

Вопрос: Как изменить регулярное выражение(нельзя изменять сам ip), чтобы выдавал False. P.S Возможно ли как нибудь аккуратно это оформить ? Ну, чтобы не было длинной строки, выходящей за экран или что-то в этом духе

Comment: чем не устраивают регулярки IP из гугла? Ваша регулярка явно хуже чем многое из того, что можно найти по элементарному запросу "регулярное выражение ip" (та же `((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)`). У вас какие-то специфические ip проверяются? Опишите тогда пару примеров того, какие должны пропускаться, а какие нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `\Z` вместо `$`, если не хотите найти совпадение в том случае, если за валидным IP следует знак перехода на новую строку, который является последним символом в строке. `\Z` находит только *самый* конец строки. Для пущей верности можно также заменить `^` на `\A`, который независимо от модификаторов всегда нвходит только начало строки. Это не требуется в случае, когда шаблон используется в методе `re.match` (он и так требует совпадения только в начале строки), но если кому-то придется использовать этот шаблон в `re.search`, тогда этот "якорь" пригодится.

Также рекомендуется квантифицировать последние 3 повторения "октетов", так будет эффективнее.

Решение:

```
\A(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}\Z
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/WZT4Bq/1).

[Демо на Python](https://ideone.com/xlTBuG):

```
import re

octet = r'(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'
rx = re.compile(r"\A{0}(?:\.{0}){{3}}\Z".format(octet))

def ipv4_address(ip):
        return bool(rx.match(ip))

strs = ["127.0.0.1\n","127.0.0.2"]
for s in strs:
    print("'{}' => {}".format(s, ipv4_address(s)))
```

Результат:

```
'127.0.0.1
' => False
'127.0.0.2' => True
```